# JSON content from API not shown in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am building this simple app where I am getting a JSON from an open weather API and displaying some of its content in the html using jQuery. Now the problem is that even though I pass the correct url inside `$getJSON()` I can't display anything. The link to the github repo is: https://github.com/gerak1925/local_weather

Incase you only want the code here you go:

```
var lat, lon;
var url = "";

function processJSON(url)
{
    $.getJSON(url, function(obj)
    {
        var temper = parseFloat(obj.main.temp) - 273.15;
        var weatherIcon = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + obj.weather[0].icon + '.png';

        $('#content').html('<p>' + temper.toString() + ' <span id="unit">Celsius</span></p>');
        $('#content').append("<p>" + obj.weather[0].description + "</p>");
        $('#content').append("<p>" + obj.main.humidity + " humidity</p>");
        $('#content').append('<p><img src="' + weatherIcon + '" /></p>');
    });
}

function geoFind()
{
    var output = document.getElementById("content");

    $('button').hide();

    if (!navigator.geolocation) 
    {
        output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
        return;
    }

    function success(position) 
    {
        lat  = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;

        url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat.toString() + "&lon=" + lon.toString() + "&APPID=5b1a0c598f588ad14577a6cfc89433b2";
    };

    function error() 
    {
        output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
    };

    output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}

$('button').on('click',geoFind);
processJSON(url);
```

The necessary html is:

```
<div id="content">

</div>
<button class="btn btn-default">Generate Weather</button>
```

The JSON I get is:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lat": 36.69,
    "lon": 23.04
  },
  "weather": [
    {

      "id": 801,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "few clouds",
      "icon": "02d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "cmc stations",
  "main": {

    "temp": 299.451,
    "pressure": 1023.76,
    "humidity": 93,
    "temp_min": 299.451,
    "temp_max": 299.451,
    "sea_level": 1025.84,
    "grnd_level": 1023.76
  },
  "wind": {

    "speed": 2.51,
    "deg": 48.5054
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 12

  },
  "dt": 1467905351,
  "sys": {

    "message": 0.0059,
    "country": "GR",
    "sunrise": 1467861381,
    "sunset": 1467913755
  },
  "id": 251465,
  "name": "Gefyra",
  "cod": 200

}
```

Ps. Yes, I've read similar posts even for same apps but with no luck.

Comment: I think you have to use POST request here.

Comment: Please clarify "*I can't display anything*".  What do you get with `$.getJSON(url, function(obj) { console.dir(obj); });`

Comment: the url might not be set, as highlighted by @freedomn-m below...to debug this well, you can look through your browser developer console for errors..also add this to your ajax call, it helps to get feedback in case of errors (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/): $.getJSON(url, function(obj){
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});

Comment: Ok so after I added the `.fail` function I got some useful info: `Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` which points to the JSON object itself, but I don't get what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the getJSON call to the following as POST is expected here.

```
$.post(url, function(obj)
    {
        var temper = parseFloat(obj.main.temp) - 273.15;
        var weatherIcon = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + obj.weather[0].icon + '.png';

        $('#content').html('<p>' + temper.toString() + ' <span id="unit">Celsius</span></p>');
        $('#content').append("<p>" + obj.weather[0].description + "</p>");
        $('#content').append("<p>" + obj.main.humidity + " humidity</p>");
        $('#content').append('<p><img src="' + weatherIcon + '" /></p>');
    },'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you've provided is the code you're using, you're not setting `url` until *after* you've already attempted the lookup:

```
$('button').on('click',geoFind);
processJSON(url);  // at this point url is still blank
```

Confirm this by changing the process function to:

```
function processJSON(url)
{
    alert(url);
```

Because the code uses callbacks, you'll need to call processJSON after you've set the url, in the success callback of the geolocation lookup:

```
function success(position) 
{
    lat  = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;

    url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat.toString() + "&lon=" + lon.toString() + "&APPID=5b1a0c598f588ad14577a6cfc89433b2";

    processJSON(url); 
};
```

Comment: I did both and the url that's being printed via alert is the correct one but still those paragraphs from `processJSON` are not being displayed. Also correct me if i'm wrong but the url I declared it at the start of the script which makes it global?!

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it's global, but where you declare it at the start, it's "":  `var url = "";` which is how it is until it's set to something else.  It might be that in your code you're giving it a default value, but in the question's code, when it hits processJSON, it's still "".

Comment: Hmm ok, so I changed the code and added what you said above. I see the url from the `alert(url)` inside `processJSON` but after that I get the following error in the console: `Request Failed: error, NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied`. So I guess this has something to do with the API?

Comment: Well at least you now know that you're calling the API correctly... looks like you have a valid APPID as I can get data when using your ID.  Maybe you overloaded it with tests?   Or the url being built does not generate the expected url - `console.log(url)` and try it in the browser directly.

Comment: I set up a local server using xampp and I saw that it was trying to GET from the following url `http://localhost/.../api.openweathermap`. That's normal or this is what causes the problem?